# Active Record query to match every subset element

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my RoR application, I've got a database lookup similar to this one:

```
Client.joins(:products).where({'product.id' => [1,2,3]})
```

Unfortunately this will return all clients that have bought product 1, 2 or 3 but I only want to get back the clients, that bought **all** of the three products. In other words, I'd like to write a query that matches for n elements in a given set.

Are there any elegant solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same answer with more dynamic way

```
ids = [1,2,3]

Client.joins(:products).
       where({'products.id' => ids}).
       group('users.id').
       having('COUNT(DISTINCT products.id) >= ?', ids.size)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not really elegant. But it should translate into the needed SQL.

```
Client.joins(:products).
       where({'products.id' => [1,2,3]}).
       group('users.id').
       having('COUNT(DISTINCT products.id) >= 3')
```

Comment: what if the same product was bought for 3 times?

Comment: @emaillenin: `DISTINCT` should be able to handle that.

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1 (I was going to do a `GROUP_CONCAT` and `having  mygroup_sorted == '1 2 3'` but your solution is brilliant :-))